# error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: php, curl

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.01
PHP: 7/0
```

Based on some googling, and input from questions on StackOverflow, I am setting the following Curl options:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,   
CURLOPT_CAINFO  = '/etc/ssl/certs',
```

I verified that /etc/ssl/certs directory exists, and that it is current.

I also modified the file /etc/php/7.0/cli/php/ini:

```
openssl.capath='/etc/ssl/certs'
```

When I try to make the Curl call, I get the following error:

```
[error] => error setting certificate verify locations:
    CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
```

I edited the permissions in the /etc/ssl/certs to:

```
rwxr-xr-x
```

But I am getting the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CURLOPT_CAINFO` should only be set if the certs you want to use are in just one file.  If you want use a whole directory (as you would typically want to do on Ubuntu), only set the `CURLOPT_CAPATH` value.

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> CURLOPT_CAINFO: The name of a file holding one or more certificates to verify the peer with.
>
> CURLOPT_CAPATH: A directory that holds multiple CA certificates.