# error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: cert.pem CApath: /etc/ssl/certs

Tags: php, ssl, curl, mtls

I have to send a request to a server with mTLS. The certificate I have to send has to be .pem and have no keys or passwords. I don't understand much about certificates yet, but I managed to organize the code bellow, however, I've been trying to solve this issue for the last hours and tried many things from many places, yet nothing seems to work.
The code i'm using to send the requests is:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', "Authorization: Bearer $bearer"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'cert.pem'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);

    $return = curl_exec($ch);

    if (!$return) {
        $return = curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);
```

And the error it's returning is:

> error setting certificate verify locations:
>
> > CAfile: cert.pem
> > CApath: /etc/ssl/certs

I've tried reinstalling and updating ca-certificates, copying and pasting the cert.pem in the /etc/ssl/certs and the /etc/pki/tls/certs folders, recreate the cert.pem file. Yet nothing changed the error.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/43785878/1427878, you should not use both CURLOPT_CAINFO and CURLOPT_CAPATH at the same time. You did not explicitly use CURLOPT_CAPATH in your code, but the error mentions a value for it - so likely that comes from your general PHP/cURL configuration. Try and specify the full path with CURLOPT_CAINFO, and set CURLOPT_CAPATH to NULL.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the issue. I set the CURLOPT_CAPATH to the path to the certificate and deleted the CURLOPT_CAINFO. It's working now... (kinda, I'm still having issues with self signed certificates and bad certificate alerts, but those I can try to solve). So, again, thank you.